# How to change the source of an audio tag with a file anywhere in my computer

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, jsp, tomcat

Currently I'm working on a project and I'm new to eclipse and server stuff.

I'm doing a Dynamic Web Project of a music player. What I'm trying to do is to change the current song playing for another one in a given directory for Example:

I have a Library of music in my computer: `/home/user/Music/Library`

And inside of Library there are my songs, what I'm trying to do is change the source of my audio tag with the path of the song I want:

```
<audio id="audioPlayer">
    <source id = "source" src="/Songs/song1" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("source").src = "/home/user/Music/Library/song1.mp3";
    document.getElementById("audioPlayer").load();
</script>
```

When I run this it throws and error 404 (Not Found).

I have an idea of the problem, maybe the server is running into a specific path and the directory doesn't exist there.

I don't want to add the songs into the project, I want the user to specify the path of the library of music.

I am using Apache-Tomcat 8.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: You need to access that file from an URL address, not the path on disk.

Comment: @Triby how would I do that? You mean like sending the path through the URL? can you refer me to a page where that is explained?